# Spring CRON Expression Help- everyday day starting sunday at 8

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, cron-task, cronexpression

I would like to create a cron expression which runs my program starting at 8pm Sunday, and runs every 15 minutes until Friday at 8 pm. Can someone help? I have this so far but I can't seem to get it right

0 0/15 20-20 * * SUN-FRI

Comment: Do you want the application to be called externally (e.g. from a cron job) or start the application and then within that running application have a recurring/scheduled task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `0 0/15 20-8,8-20 ? * SUN,MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *`

This site looks pretty great for that: http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: Thank you for your response! Wouldn't that start at 8am on Sunday though?

Comment: This is where I get confused! Now doesn't this mean it starts at 8pm on Monday? Additionally, wouldn't this expression run only from 8:00 - 8:45pm?

Comment: Just updated an answer. I think you cannot achive this: `until Friday at 8 pm` It is too complicated for cron expression. **It will end at Friday 11:45 pm**.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for your responses. Just one last question, does this cause the code to run at 8am on Sunday? (8-20)

Comment: This part `20-8,8-20` says: run task from 8pm to 8am and from 8am to 8pm. It is need for this part `starting at 8pm Sunday` because you need to start at 8pm on that day.